# Angular 6 como deixar campo default no select?

Tags: html, angular

Estou tentando deixar um dos elementos option como selected, porém não consigo colocar para funcionar no Angular 6.

**app.component.html:**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="marcaSelecionada" class="form-control" name="marca" required>
  <option value="">Selecione uma marca...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let marca of marcas" [ngValue]="marca.id">{{ marca.nome_marca | uppercase }}</option>
</select>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AtualizaFormularioService } from './atualiza-formulario.service';

interface MarcaModelo {
  id?: string;
  nome_marca?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public marcas: MarcaModelo[];
  public campoMarca: MarcaModelo = {
    nome_marca: ''
  }
  public marcaSelecionada: string = '2';

}
```

Comment: Nesse seu caso o id do do objeto que vc esta comparando tem que ser igual o que vc deixou por padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar o atributo value da tag select com o valor que você deseja que ele carregue selecionado:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="marcaSelecionada" class="form-control" name="marca" value="marcaSelecionada" required>
  <option value="">Selecione uma marca...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let marca of marcas" [ngValue]="marca.id">{{ marca.nome_marca | uppercase }}</option>
</select>
```

[- Pergunta relacionada.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009331/select-default-option-value-from-typescript-angular-6)

[- Segue um exemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwdref?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)